# Webparts to be aligned in a SPS2013 Webpage based on the screen resolution of user machine?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server, view

Environment: SPS2013

While viewing Intranet Homepage from

- IE11
- default screen resolution: 1920 * 1080,

Webpage appears fine.

- Screen resolution: 1600 * 780,

Web-parts alignment gets disturbed.

In google Chrome, webparts don't appear properly even in the default resolution.

Any suggestion to take care of such simple yet difficult issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "gets disturbed"?

Comment: Alignment is disturbed, not in proper alignment anymore.

Comment: I understand that, but what exactly? widths? heights? positioning? Could you provide screenshots?

Comment: Position , even though set float: left. Ony in chrome, works fine on IE.